# Handling Special char such as ^ÛY, ^ÛR in java

Tags: java, special-characters, non-ascii-characters

Has anybody encountered special char such as ^ÛY, ^ÛR ?

Q1. How do I do an ftp of the files containing these chars? The chars are not seen once I do a ftp on AIX (bi or ascii) and hence I am unable to see my program to replace these, working.

Q2. My java program doesn't seem to recognise these or replace these if I search for these explicitly (^ÛY, ^ÛR ) in the file however a replace using regular expression seems to work (I could only see the difference in the length of the string). My program is executed on AIX. Any insights why java cannot recognise these?

Q3. Does the Oracle database recognise these chars? An update is failing where my program indicates the string to be of lesser length and without these characters but the db complains "value too large for column" as the string to be updated contains these chars and hence longer.

thanks in advance,

RJ

Comment: Are you talking about non-ASCII alphabet characters such as Unicode letters, or are you talking about control codes below ASCII 0x20?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the characters you talk about are non-Latin alphabet letters encoded in file contents used specific encodings.

There are separate solutions for each section of the setup: AIX, Java and Oracle.

Basically, for AIX and Oracle separately you would need to adapt locale settings to match the content you are trying to work with.

I am not sure of the exact procedure on AIX, but you would need to set locale settings on server, and then update your telnet/ssh program settings that you use to connect with, to allow you to write/see appropriate chars.

This should incidentally fix Java as well, as it would recognize the locale settings, but if you need manual tweaking google for Java + LOCALE, perhaps here: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/locale/

It seems should work for Oracle too, but once again you might need to do some extra such as tweaking NLS_LANG variable: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.ii.doc/opt/tlsorc13.htm

Comment: These characters got into the file when a ftp transfer was done from an external system into out AIX box. Unable to check what encoding / charset these belong to, so that we can try corresponding settings. These are some unwanted junk chars that need to be removed. Also unable to replicate when we do an ftp internally from one box to another.

Comment: Sounds like FTP binary/ascii mode mixup on the side of the client who is uploading the file to AIX.
Do you have option to get the file via other means (email for example) and feed to AIX via other internal system to see, if it works?